# I want to convert long int values into HH:MM format in Java

Tags: java, datetime, time, type-conversion, long-integer

- **-1800000** - `04:00`
- **-19800000** - `05 : 00`

I have highlighted the int values I am getting from the code. The actual values are given. I want to write code to convert these long Integer values into `HH:MM` format.

Comment: These are in 24h clock format

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: How do these long integer values encode the time?

Comment: nothing only i know is real values of these integers

Comment: Is that a time of day (4 AM and 5 AM) or an amount of time (4 hours and 5 hours, like a duration)? `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, handles those two cases differently. If it’s a time of day, in which time zone? I suspect it matters.

Comment: I cannot make sense of your long values. If they were milliseconds, the first would be minus half an hour and the second minus 5 and a half hours. It doesn’t seem to explain how there are one hour between them, nor how the latter translates to more hours than the former.

Comment: If this is all you know, one solution is to build a `Map<Long, String>`. Store your conversions there. Look the right one up when you receive a long. It would be adventurous, though. You’d better find out more about what the expected conversion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that neither you nor I understand which conversion is expected here. I cannot solve that for you. I’d like to share a thought, though, it may be that it may help you a bit on the way.

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    long longValue = -1_800_000;
    String formattedTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kabul"))
            .format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

This prints the expected.

> 04:00

I am assuming that the long value denotes milliseconds since the epoch, this would be very commonplace. It agrees with the local time in Asia/Kabul and Asia/Tehran time zones, I don’t know whether there are other time zones that may fit.

If this explanation is to hold, we will have to assume that there is a bug in the other value, though. I could not find a time zone where that value would fit with a time of 05:00. Also if the values belong to different time zones, you don’t stand a chance unless they are telling which time zones they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
    String date = month_date.format(cal.getTime()).toString();
    System.out.println(date);
    return date;
}
```

This give me the answer but there is a variation of one or two mins

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. If you insist on using it yourself, specifying lowercase `mm` for minutes will help. Beware that result will differ depending on the time zone setting of the JVM where you run your program.